# Puppet and Postgres annoying warning: Passing "version" to postgresql::server is deprecated

Tags: postgresql, puppet

I'm using the puppet-postgresql module to manage PostgreSQL. That part of the manifest looks like this:

```
class { 'postgresql::server':
    postgres_password          => 'postgres',
}
postgresql::server::db { $db_name:
    user     => $db_user,
    password => postgresql_password($db_user, $db_password),
}
```

Works fine but I get the annoying warning:

```
Warning: Scope(Class[Postgresql::Server]): Passing "version" to postgresql::server is deprecated; please use postgresql::globals instead.
```

**EDIT:**
I even added the version to the globals, but I'm still getting the warning:

```
class { 'postgresql::globals':
  version             => '9.3',
}->
class { 'postgresql::server':
    postgres_password          => 'postgres',
}
postgresql::server::db { $db_name:
    user     => $db_user,
    password => postgresql_password($db_user, $db_password),
}
```

But I'm not passing any **'version'** to `postgresql::server`. What I'm doing wrong here?

Docs https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/postgresql didn't helped me in this case...

Comment: This Should Not Happen. If you don't specify a version, the module should use [the default](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-postgresql/blob/master/manifests/server.pp#L49) of `undef` and generate no warning. Are you using Hiera? Does it perhaps contain the `postgresql::server::version` key?

Comment: No Hiera. I'm not very experimented with puppet manifests, but I looked at the code and think the problem is that ::server inherits from ::params which also inherits the `version` from ::globals. The way the warning is implemented in server.pp can't differentiate between an inherited `version` or an overrided one, thus giving a Warning even when the variable wasn't overrided. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, upon further reading it had struck me as weird as well. Confirmed by m0dlx in his below comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug in the puppetlabs-postgresql module in the 3.4.x series.  It's since been fixed in [PR 471](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-postgresql/pull/471) which will be released in the next major version (4.0.0 by the looks of it).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify the version, a default version is selected by the module in the file `manifests/globals.pp`. So you can either edit this file to specify a newer version for your OS or pass the version in parameter when calling `postgresql::server`

Comment: Then I think the warning is wrong. Because I'm not setting it in ::server. I'm letting ::global guess the defaults, and even passing the version but still getting the warning.

Comment: from file `server.pp` this message is displayed only when `$version != undef` !

Comment: I'm not very experimented with puppet manifests, but I looked at the code and think the problem is that ::server inherits from ::params which also inherits the version from ::globals. The way the warning is implemented in server.pp can't differentiate between an inherited `version` or an overrided one, thus giving a Warning even when the variable wasn't overrided. What do you think?

Comment: The warning is indeed wrong, it's a bug in the latest version of the module.  [PR 471](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-postgresql/pull/471) fixes it.

Comment: m0dlx is right. if you want you can write it as answer and I will accept it.