# Puppet use pre-existing version of postgres

Tags: postgresql, configuration, puppet, rpm

I am doing an RPM based install with the relevant bits as follows:

**RPM**

```
Requires: puppet => 3.7.4 , postgresql94 => 9.4.1

%post  
puppet apply test.pp
```

**test.pp**

```
node 'foo'{  
     class{ 'postgresql::server':
   }
}
```

I want to configure the version of postgres that gets installed by the `Requires` element from my RPM.  However, I have been unable to find a way to force puppet to use the one that already exists.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you are seeing PostgreSQL upgraded.  In that case, the cause would be either your requires line (what *is* the version that already exists?), or something buried in puppet's globals (as noted in [Puppet and PostgreSQL annoying warning: Passing “version” to postgresql::server is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25606454/puppet-and-postgres-annoying-warning-passing-version-to-postgresqlserver-is)).